# Using Measure as a Filter Parameter

Tags: powerbi

The following code provides the desired result:
FY22 Cum Invoice Total =

```
var SetOfDates=DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date],[FirstInvoiceMonthFY],[FirstDayThisMonth])
return

CALCULATE(
   SUM('Invoice Amounts'[CLIN Total]),SetOfDates)
```

Since I use similar calculations repeatedly, I wanted to make the SetOfDates variable into a standalone measure:

```
DateFilter = DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date],[FirstInvoiceMonthFY],[FirstDayThisMonth])
```

When I substitute this measure I get an error:

```
FY22 Cum Invoice Total = 
// var SetOfDates=DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date],[FirstInvoiceMonthFY],[FirstDayThisMonth])
// return

CALCULATE(
   SUM('Invoice Amounts'[CLIN Total]),[DateFilter])
```

The Error:  A function 'PLACEHOLDER' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

Is this a simple syntax error?

Comment: Any help on this one?

Answer (score 0):

This is a lineage issue and the solution is the same as I posted here: [Using Measure as Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72972821/using-measure-as-variable)