# Using Measure as Variable

Tags: powerbi, dax

The following measure works, but rather than making separate measures for each year, I want to use a variable in place of 2022.
Q1FY22 Cost = CALCULATE(
SUM('Invoice Amounts'[CLIN Total]),'Calendar'[Fiscal Year]=2022,'Calendar'[Fiscal Quarter]=1)

I created another measure,

```
ThisFY=2022
```

When I substitute in the original,

```
Q1FY22 Cost = CALCULATE(
    SUM('Invoice Amounts'[CLIN Total]),'Calendar'[Fiscal Year]=[ThisFY],'Calendar'[Fiscal Quarter]=1)
```

I receive the error:  A function 'PLACEHOLDER' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

Comment: Does it work with this as a workaround: ```Q1FY22 Cost = VAR vThisFY = [ThisFY] RETURN CALCULATE(
    SUM('Invoice Amounts'[CLIN Total]),'Calendar'[Fiscal Year]=vThisFY,'Calendar'[Fiscal Quarter]=1)```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lineage issue.

Try this.

```
Q1FY22 Cost = CALCULATE(
    SUM('Invoice Amounts'[CLIN Total]), TREATAS( {[ThisFY]}, 'Calendar'[Fiscal Year]),'Calendar'[Fiscal Quarter]=1)
```